# ToastController custom position in ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2, android-toast

We are creating Ionic-Native mobile app.We are using ToastController ([ToastController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toast/ToastController/)).We used **position: 'top'** .But it overlaps to status bar.So we want custom position .We tried like this

```
let Errortoast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: 'Please try again later',
      duration: 3000,
      cssClass: 'toast',
      position: 'top'
    });



    .toast{
    margin-top: 70px;
  }
```

But no luck .Any idea for Custom position ?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `transform: translateY(70px);` as a CSS property to move the `Toast` down.

Here is a full code example:

**yourPage**.ts

```
this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: 'Please try again later',
    duration: 3000,
    cssClass: 'yourClass',
    position: 'top'
}).present();
```

**yourPage**.css

```
.yourClass {
    .toast-wrapper {
        transform: translateY(70px) !important;
    } 
}
```

**Note**: This CSS code snippet needs to be out of the `page` CSS because the `.toast-wrapper` is outside of the page.

Comment: I had to remove the `.toast-wrapper` selector, see https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17499

Answer (score 2):

Translate did not work in my case, because I needed to have the footer of my app clickable (transform does not really move the elememnt, so it was just overlapping).

It worked with this SCSS:

```
ion-toast {
    height: calc(100% - #{$my-footernav-height});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For angular and ionic...

```
this.toastCtrl.create({
 message: 'Please try again later',
 duration: 3000,
 cssClass: 'toast-custom-class',
 position: 'top'
}).present();

::ng-deep .toast-custom-class {
   transform: translateY(-50px) !important; //or whatever you want here.
}
```